# Redis Ignoring directory in redis.conf

Tags: redis, osx-mountain-lion

I recently installed Redis on OS X.  I did an initial load of some objects, everything in this regard seems to be working perfectly.

I saved the data to `dump.rdb` and if I launch redis from this directory and don't use a `redis.conf` file everything goes according to plan.

The problem is that after settling in and setting up a `redis.conf` file in `/etc/redis/` it seems to completely ignore the `dbfilename` and `dir` settings.

To be more clear.  I created a data directory in: `/Library/Redis_Data/`.
In the `redis.conf` I set `dbfilename dump.rdb` and `dir /Library/Redis_Data`

If I launch: `redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf` it simply refuses to load the `dump.rdb`.

I've run `redis-cli` and can read the config parameters `get config dbfilename` and `get config dir` and they return the correct values, but no data gets restored.

I also enabled AOF.  The file `appendonly.aof` which resides in the same directory will be recreated if I delete it and start the server again.

Lastly...if I run `save` from the cli it will completely wipe out and create a new `dump.rdb` over my data.

Any thoughts?

> FYI: redis server v=2.6.9 sha=00000000:0 malloc=libc bits=64

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Solved:
Looking back this morning on this issue I managed to discover the problem.

I originally added my data without enabling `appendonly` mode.  After this test load I setup my environment and decided it would be great to enable `appendonly`.

What I discovered is this. If you have data in the `dump.rdb` but the `appendonly.aof` file is empty **and** `appendonly` is turned on; Redis will ignore the `dump.rdb` instead assuming there is nothing to be done because the `appendonly.aof` transactions don't exist.

What I did:  Turned off `appendonly` in the config file and restarted Redis with the normal directory setup.  This then loaded the `dump.rdb` as per my config file.  I then ran the command from `redis-cli config set appendonly yes` followed by `save`.

This then created the `appendonly.aof` file with all the transactions.  Set `appendonly` back to `yes` in the config and all was right.

Cheers,
damnabit

Comment: Thanks for this, I couldn't understand why Redis kept ignoring my dump file, and then when I enabled `appendonly` and restarted it, it deleted the dump file. Changing the config USING redis-cli and calling `save` was the part I was missing!